# Warning: mysqli_stmt_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt

Tags: php, html, mssql

Estoy haciendo un formulario prueba con *PHP* y cuando lo lleno y doy enviar el navegador me da el error:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, bool given in D:\xammp\htdocs\formularios\CRUD\create.php on line 119

Que es aquí  `mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);` no se que pueda haber hecho mal y estoy mareado de tanto buscar si alguien me puede ayudar se los agradecería inmensamente, dejo el código aquí abajo muchas gracias por su tiempo.

```
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $param_nombre, $param_email, $param_investigador, $param_fecha, $param_clase, $param_tipo, $param_ciudadcaso, $param_condicionjuridica, $param_cliente,);
            
            // Set parameters
            $param_nombre = $nombre;
            $param_email = $email;
            $param_investigador = $investigador;
            $param_fecha = $fecha;
            $param_clase = $clase;
            $param_tipo = $tipo;
            $param_ciudadcaso = $ciudadcaso;
            $param_condicionjuridica = $condicionjuridica;
            $param_cliente = $cliente;
            
            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Records created successfully. Redirect to landing page
                header("location: index.php");
                exit();
            } else{
                echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }
         
        // Close statement   //aqui me da el errror
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);  
    }
    
    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fijate donde la estás cerrando

```
if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
    []...
}
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
```

Debes intentar cerrar dentro del if a pesar de que haya fallado.

```
if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
    []...
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);  
}
```

Ahora, si quieres hacer una captura de la falla, te recomiendo usar el else para ello, y crear un echo, alerta, o lo que te parezca necesario utilizar para mostrar el error de conexión.

Comment: Pero si ya fue respondido, se supone que si ya existe, deba redirigir.

Comment: Entiendo, muchas gracias por la aclaracion, entonces es aceptable que haya dejado la resolucion al conflicto debajo ??

Comment: gracias por tu tiempo hermano. lo cerre dentro de if y no me da ningun error pero no me pasa informacion a la base de datos

Comment: Un error menos jajaja suerte con el sgte

Comment: sera que el mysqli_close($link); tambien deba cerrarlo dentro? psdt: soy nuevo en esto

Comment: No lo creo, esa es la conexión mysqli. El nuevo problema puede ser totalmente diferente a este. Te recomiendo hacer una captura de error durante el else para descartar errores nuevos. Sino, podrìa ser durante la consulta a la BBDD que no pasa nada, pero ya no tiene que ver con el tema anterior.